# What is the most easiest way to make a simple sponge in blender?

Tags: shaders

What is the easiest way to make a photo-realistic sponge? I am just asking this question out of curiosity and boredom. I know the modelling is really easy and I got that covered but the shading is kind of confusing and I am not really sure how to make the shading for a sponge. So I have a simple question in my mind, how do you make a cool simple sponge in blender with a very simple but photorealistic shading?

I want a simple answer!!

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my proposition: A mix of 2 *Noise Texture* and one *Voronoi* nodes, one with small orange dots on a yellow background, another one with a little bit bigger white dots, and at last the big orange holes. I use the same mix for a *Bump* node. I put the *Specular* at 0 and the *Roughness* at 1. I also give it a bit of *Subsurface*. For real holes, or aven if you want a bit of relief on the edges, you could use a *Displace* modifier (with *Voronoi* texture) or sculpt some holes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hummm grainy cheese

Comment: @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I would say cheesy sponge